# How to simplify line geometry and preserving topology in Oracle?

Tags: topology, oracle-spatial, simplify

I have some polylines in an Oracle database which are topologically connected and I want to simplify these lines based on a tolerance directly in Oracle. I need something like st_simplifypreservetopology in PostGIS to use in Oracle.

Comment: If you split lines at joins the connectness should remain with normal simplification.

Comment: What if they disconnect instead?